# Does the bundle ID have to use reverse domain notation?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Does an app bundle ID have to use reverse domain notation, or can it be anything as long as it's unique, for example `companyname.myappname`?

Comment: It can be anything, its good to have domain as ID, as they are unique, it reduces burden of thinking of an unique name, so normally we do companydomain.appname

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html), under 'About Bundle IDs' section:

> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.). The string **should** be in reverse-DNS format. For example, if your organization’s domain is Acme.com and you create an app named Hello, you could assign the string com.Acme.Hello as your app’s bundle ID.

It says string SHOULD be in revers-DNS, not MUST be!